# How do permalinks get stored?

Tags: apache, jsp, permalinks

I would like to implement permalinks on my website (I use JSP+Servlets if this makes any difference) and was wondering how they work. Are they stored as physical pages on the server or values go into the database and URLs are generated dynamically?

For example, http://jsfiddle dot netnet/8MBHZ/

Is 8MBHZ a physical html page?

Comment: No; they're just handling raw HTTP requests in server-side code.  URLs do not need to have anything to do with files.

Comment: @SLaks so there must be something that looks for those key values in URLs. Will it be a servlet in my case or something else on apache side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the static URL of the page. Such request comes to the server, the value `8MBHZ` is retrieved from the URL. Using this value, you can find the page content in the database. Then this extracted content is rendered.

(Static URLs are not indexed multiple times (in contrast to dynamic). This has a positive effect on search engine optimization (SEO)).

Comment: Static URL must have a static, physical page associated with it, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Ok, so once content is stored it is associated with id (8MBHZ for example). I think I got it. So, what is monitoring server URLs for permalink IDs? Is this done on Apache httpd level?